# sum column and row for specific value in R

Tags: r

I have data frame like this:

[image]

I want to get something like this:

[image: result]

Please advice me how to do that. Thanks!

I've tried with `ddply` but it pops up an error saying the function is not found.
I also tried using `aggregate` but it sum all the columns regardless of category column.

Comment: If you are summing up `data_A` and `data_C`, then `aggregate(data_A~category, cbind(df1['category', data_A = rowSums(df1[c('data_A', 'data_C')])), FUN = sum)`

Comment: Why don't you include the data directly instead of images?

Comment: Please include code and code to create the data into the question

Comment: Or use `library(dplyr);df1 %>% group_by(category) %>% summarise(data_A = sum(data_A + data_C))`

Comment: thanks @akrun, your code really help me

Comment: how to mark this as solved?

Comment: @AlexBradley  Thanks, I posted my comments as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by 'category', then add the 'data_A' and 'data_C' and get the `sum` of it

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarise(data_A = sum(data_A + data_C))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   category data_A
#    <fctr>  <dbl>
#1        A      8
#2        B     60
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(category = c('A', 'B', 'A'), data_A = c(3, 20, 1), 
                  data_B = c(100, 200, 400), data_C = c(1, 40, 3))
```